# Error ------ unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, mysql-python, eof

I am running this code on Python 3(IDLE) on my raspberry pi 3 whith the latest raspbian software. With this code I am trying to obtain temperature data through ds18b20 sensor and sending that same data towards the mysql database I created.

From the try: to the end of the if connection.is_connected(), I am establishing the connection to the mysql database.

From the if os.system('modprobe w1-gpio') to  return temp_c, I am obtaining the temperature data through the ds18b20 sensor.

From the Whiletrue to the end of my code, I try to send the temperature data into a specific table intitled TAB_CLASSROOM.

Help would be very much appreciated!

HERE IS THE FULL ERROR!:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/mysqlfinal1test.py", line 74
    db.close()
              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Here is the python including mysql code :

```
import os
import glob
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

i = datetime.datetime.now()

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             database='temp_pi',
                             user='root',
                             password='test')

    if connection.is_connected():
       db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
       print("Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on ",db_Info)
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute("select database();")
       record = cursor.fetchone()
       print ("Your connected to - ", record)

    os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
    os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

    def read_temp_raw():
        f = open(device_file, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines

    def read_temp():
        lines = read_temp_raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
            time.sleep(0.2)
            lines = read_temp_raw()
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos != -1:
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
            temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
            return temp_c  

        while True:
              print("recording data into database(period = 5s.)....press ctrl+Z to stop!")

              valT = str(read_temp())

              year = str(i.year)
              month = str(i.month)
              day = str(i.day)
              date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

              hour = str(i.hour)
              minute = str(i.minute)
              second = str(i.second)
              timestr = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

              try:
                 cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TAB_CLASSROOM(temp_c,T_Date,T_Time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(valT,date,time))
                 db.commit()
              except:
                 db.rollback()

              time.sleep(10)

        cur.close()  
        db.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of posted program is a huge `try` block with no `except` clause.  Thus, when the parser hits the bottom of the file, it has no way to finish off the open control block.

The `try` is at line 11; we run out of input after line 74, without any `except` for that `try`.

I suspect that your indentation is faulty (among other things), since this `try` includes two function definitions.  Still, you have two `try` statements, and only the one `except`.

Comment: I did add an except clause at the end. That's why I am confused @Prune

Comment: You have an `except` that's inside the `while` loop of `read_temp`.  You have no `except` for the `try` at line 11.

Comment: ahhh thank you the error went away! I updated my code. But now it won't run the rest of the code after the except error that I have.

Comment: (1) That's a separate problem, requiring a separate question; (2) You haven't posted the offending code, so there's no way we can diagnose the problem; (3) Just a wild shot: did you *handle* the exception?  If not ... well, read the documentation on the `try - except` construct.

Comment: Alright well you answered my question! Lol but I now have a different problem. Thanks for your help tho! Any tips on how I could fix the problem of python not being able to run the rest of my code after I establish the connection to the database? @Prune

Comment: I gave you those tips in my previous comment.